# basic virus scan recursion

Tags: python, recursion, virus

so I'm writing code that takes a `pathname`, a `signature`, and the third parameter is a `number` that represents the depth of subdirectories that should be scanned.

So lets say I have a **file: test**:

```
In it is test1 folder,test2 folder,antivirus.py,simple.py
In test1 folder is antivirus1.py
In test2 folder is test3 folder, and antivirus2.py
In test3 folder is antivirus3.py
```

**So this is how it should work:**

```
>>>scan('test',rules, 0)
test\antivirus.py, found virus Virus2
test\antivirus.py, found virus Virus1
>>>
>>>scan('test',rules, 2)
test\antivirus.py, found virus Virus2
test\antivirus.py, found virus Virus1
test\test1\antivirus1.py, found virus Virus2
test\test1\antivirus1.py, found virus Virus1
test\test2\antivirus2.py, found virus Virus2
test\test2\antivirus2.py, found virus Virus1
```

**Here is my current code:**

```
def scan(pathname, signatures, depth):
    for item in os.listdir(pathname) and depth > 0:
        n = os.path.join(pathname, item)
        try:
            scan(n, signatures, depth-1)
        except:
            f = open(n, 'r')
            s = f.read()
            for virus in signatures:
                if s.find(signatures[virus]) > 0:
                    print('{}, found virus {}'.format(n,virus))
            f.close()
```

Comment: All I need is a push in the right direction, or some advise. But I am a novice so go easy on me.

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: I am having trouble implementing the depth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` loops don't really work like that. Their syntax is `for <variable> in <iterable>`.

Just us an `if` statement instead:

```
if depth <= 0:
    return

for item in os.listdir(pathname):
```